# Login works on local server not on live server

Tags: php, sql

My login of admin panel and member panel both works fine on local server, But on Live server member panel doesn't work. As admin and member panel both use same connection file so it means connection file works fine. More over when we fill wrong user or password it says

> Invalid User or Password

But when we login with correct user or password  it returns back with no indication of error.

My login file upper php part is:

```
<?php
    include_once("../init.php");

    $msg='';
    ?>
    <?php


    if(isset($_POST['click']))
    {
        $user = trim($_POST['user']);   
        $pass = trim($_POST['pass']);   
        if(($user =='' )|| ($pass=='')){
            $msg ='Please enter username & password';   
        }else{
            $npass = ($pass);
            $qry = mysql_query("select * from user where user ='$user'");
            if(mysql_num_rows($qry)==0) {
                $msg ='Invalid UserName';   
            } else {
                $res = mysql_fetch_array($qry);
                if($res['pass']==$npass) {


                        $_SESSION['USE_USER']       = $res['user'];
                        $_SESSION['SID']            = $res['id'];
                        $_SESSION['USE_NAME']       = $res['fname'];
                        $_SESSION['USE_SPONSOR']    = $res['sponsor'];
                        $_SESSION['PACKAGE_AMT']    = $res['package_amt'];
                        $_SESSION['ADDRESS']        = $res['address'];
                        $_SESSION['PHONE']          = $res['phone'];
                        $_SESSION['JOIN_DATE']      = $res['join_date'];
                        header('location: main.php');
                } else {
                    $msg ='Invalid Password';   
                }

            }       
        }
    }
?>
```

My header file main.php is

```
<?php

    include_once("../init.php");
    validation_check($_SESSION['SID'],MEM_HOME_ADMIN);
    $msg='';

    $dir ='../'.USER_PIC;
    $sId = $_SESSION['SID'];
?>
```

Session is started from another file called function.php

```
<?php
    function logout($destinationPath)
    {
        if(count($_SESSION))
        {
            foreach($_SESSION AS $key=>$value)
            {
                session_unset($_SESSION[$key]);
            }
            session_destroy();
        }
        echo "<script language='javaScript' type='text/javascript'>
                window.location.href='".$destinationPath."';
            </script>";
    }
    function validation_check($checkingVariable, $destinationPath)
    {
        if($checkingVariable == '')
        {
            echo "<script language='javaScript' type='text/javascript'>
                window.location.href='".$destinationPath."';
            </script>";
        }
    }
    function realStrip($input)
    {
        return mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes(trim($input)));
    }
    function no_of_record($table, $cond)
    {
        $sql    = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT FROM ".$table." WHERE ".$cond;
        $qry    = mysql_query($sql);
        $rec    = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry);
        $count  = $rec['CNT'];
        return $count;
    }
    //drop down
    function drop_down($required=null, $text_field, $table_name, $id, $name, $cond, $selected_id=null)
    {
        $qry = mysql_query("SELECT $id, $name FROM $table_name WHERE $cond ORDER BY $name ASC");
        $var = '';
        if(mysql_num_rows($qry)>0)
        {
            $var = '<select id="'.$text_field.'" name="'.$text_field.'" '.$required.'>';
            $var .='<option value="">--Choose--</option>';
            while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry))
            {
                $selected = '';
                if($selected_id==$r[$id]){
                    $selected = 'selected="selected"';
                }
                $var .='<option value="'.$r[$id].'" '.$selected.'>'.$r[$name].'</option>';
            }
            $var .='</select>';
        }
        echo $var;
    }
    function uploadResume($title,$uploaddoc,$txtpropimg)
    {
        $upload= $uploaddoc;
        $filename=$_FILES[$txtpropimg]['name'];
        $fileextension=strchr($filename,".");
        $photoid=rand();
        $newfilename=$title.$photoid.$fileextension;
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$txtpropimg]['tmp_name'],$upload.$newfilename);
        return $newfilename;
    }



    function fRecord($field, $table, $cond)
    {
        $fr = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT $field FROM $table WHERE $cond"));
        return $fr[$field];
    }


    function get_values_for_keys($mapping, $keys) {
      $output_arr = '';
      $karr = explode(',',$keys);
      foreach($karr as $key) {
       $output_arr .= $mapping[$key].', ';
      }
      $output_arr = rtrim($output_arr, ', ');
      return $output_arr;
    }

    function getBaseURL() {
    $isHttps = ((array_key_exists('HTTPS', $_SERVER) 
            && $_SERVER['HTTPS']) ||
        (array_key_exists('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', $_SERVER) 
                && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https')
    );
    return 'http' . ($isHttps ? 's' : '') .'://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
}


    function request_uri()
    {
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
    return $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    // IIS with ISAPI_REWRITE
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL'])
    return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL'];
    $p = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
    if ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])
    $p .= '?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    return $p;
    }
    preg_match ('`/'.FOLDER_NAME.'(.*)(.*)$`', request_uri(), $matches);
    $tableType = (!empty ($matches[1]) ? ($matches[1]) : '');
    $url_array=explode('/',$tableType);




?>
```

Moreover I have created user id by words and time  like LH1450429882 and column is verture type. I think this has no effect on login.

I think main errors come from function.php  Sorry for a long code, but I tried to cover all parts of coding.

I am struggling with this code from a week. Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Which PHP version you're using at your Server ?

Comment: Please check it session_id() is generated or not if not which means session is not enabled.

Comment: Missing session_start() maybe

Comment: Let me know have you checked it ?

Comment: session is started from function.php file  i have included the code you may check the code

Comment: any errors ??? ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

Comment: is there any code to generate session id in my coding  please check if not tell me how to generate or check session id

Comment: NikosDros  sir  no  errors or warnings

Comment: I do not see any `session_start()` in your function.php file. Can you verify?

Comment: @stubben I don't think its the problem with `session_start()` because then the login wouldn't work on local server too.

Comment: @stubben Sir it is working fine on local server so session_start()    is not the  problem. Problem is at another part.

Comment: @NikosDros your sugession is valuable. By implementing your code, it gives the error of header ploblem  on line 6 in login php  I have removed  ?> and <?php  in login page and make a single part php file. Now it login to my page. So credit goes to NikosDros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a bug that error_reporting  will show off. Always use it in development mode, to catch some carelessness errors and ensure the code's clarity.

```
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
```

Answer (score 0):

By implementing code  ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);   I got the error of header ploblem on line 6 in login php I have removed ?> and

Now my working code in login.php is

```
<?php
    include_once("../init.php");

    $msg='';

    if(isset($_POST['click']))
    {
        $user = trim($_POST['user']);   
        $pass = trim($_POST['pass']);   
        if(($user =='' )|| ($pass=='')){
            $msg ='Please enter username & password';   
        }else{
            $npass = ($pass);
            $qry = mysql_query("select * from user where user ='$user'");
            if(mysql_num_rows($qry)==0) {
                $msg ='Invalid UserName';   
            } else {
                $res = mysql_fetch_array($qry);
                if($res['pass']==$npass) {


                        $_SESSION['USE_USER']       = $res['user'];
                        $_SESSION['SID']            = $res['id'];
                        $_SESSION['USE_NAME']       = $res['fname'];
                        $_SESSION['USE_SPONSOR']    = $res['sponsor'];
                        $_SESSION['PACKAGE_AMT']    = $res['package_amt'];
                        $_SESSION['ADDRESS']        = $res['address'];
                        $_SESSION['PHONE']          = $res['phone'];
                        $_SESSION['JOIN_DATE']      = $res['join_date'];
                        header('location: main.php');
                } else {
                    $msg ='Invalid Password';   
                }

            }       
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Solution to my problem credit goes to @NikosDros    always use ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);  code to get errors. thanks